# How can I keep the TeX-error-overview buffer automatically being updated in particular frame in AUCTeX?

Tags: auctex

`TeX-error-overview` provides a nice overview of errors when compiling a TeX document, however the buffer does not get reused when calling it a second time. Moreover, it would be nice if it would automatically show up. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Did you try setting `TeX-error-overview-open-after-TeX-run` to t?  `M-x customize-variable RET TeX-error-overview-open-after-TeX-run RET`.